# Finding all nearest neighbour to all data points using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, knn, nearest-neighbor, sparklyr

I would like to use sparklyr find the nearest neighbour for each point in a dataset.

I've found [sparklyr::ml_approx_nearest_neighbors()](https://rdrr.io/cran/sparklyr/man/ft_lsh_utils.html) uses a `key` argument (a single feature vector) to find the nearest neighbour, so I guess I'd iterate over that for each point. Should I use this with lapply(), or is this inefficient?

Here's an example (I've modified from [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/04/local-snsitivity-hashing-model/)) where I take the titanic dataset and attempt to find the nearest 2 neighbours from the same dataset using the first 700 data points. It returns the point itself, and the next closest as expected, but I suspect the entire pipeline reruns for each data point making this inefficient.

Is there a better way, please?

```
library(sparklyr)
library(titanic)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks") # create a spark connection object

# clean dataset
df_titanic <- titanic::titanic_train %>%
  dplyr::select(Survived, Pclass, Sex, Age, SibSp, Parch, Fare) %>% 
  dplyr::rename_all(tolower) %>% # make the col names lower case
  dplyr::mutate(sex = ifelse(sex == 'male', 1, 0), id = 1:nrow(.)) %>% # turn sex to an integer
  dplyr::filter_all(dplyr::all_vars(!is.na(.))) # remove NAs

sdf_titanic <- sparklyr::copy_to(sc, df_titanic, overwrite = T) # copy to spark

input_cols <- c('pclass', 'sex', 'age', 'sibsp', 'parch', 'fare') # features list

## append a vectorised list of the features we're interested in
sdf_titanic_va <- ft_vector_assembler(sdf_titanic, 
                                      input_cols = input_cols, 
                                      output_col = 'features')

brp_lsh <- sparklyr::ft_bucketed_random_projection_lsh(
  sc,
  input_col = 'features',
  output_col = 'hash',
  bucket_length = 2,
  num_hash_tables = 3
  )

brp_fit <- ml_fit(brp_lsh, sdf_titanic_va) ## fit the LSH to our data to get the hashes

id1_input <- sdf_titanic_va %>%
  dplyr::filter(id %in% 1:700) %>%
  dplyr::pull(features) 


lapply(id1_input, function(x) ml_approx_nearest_neighbors(
  brp_fit,
  sdf_titanic_va,
  key = x,
  dist_col = 'dist_col',
  num_nearest_neighbors = 2
))
```

Comment: Have you read this https://www.eddjberry.com/post/2019-04-14_approx_knn_lsh/?

Comment: Thanks @Bruno - I did read this. The article suggests either using:
- ml_approx_similarity_join() which only finds matches under a pre-specified distance threshold, so misses pairing up points far away from others. E.g. when threshold = 1.5 in above dataset the second observation is ignored because the nearest point to it is obs 541 @ 3.01.
- Or using ml_approx_nearest_neighbors() that only finds neighbours for one obs at a time (hence my suggestion of using lapply() and looping through them, which seems inefficient)